# WPF C# databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to go along tutorial from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg610409.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg638943, but my Data Sources are empty when it should automatically get tables from entity data model. I must add Data Sources manualy. What is more, in tutorial there are automatically added methods like "GetCustomersQuery" after drag'n'drop items from Data Sources, but I have only this:

```
        WpfApplication4.DatabaseFCDataSet databaseFCDataSet = ((WpfApplication4.DatabaseFCDataSet)(this.FindResource("databaseFCDataSet")));
      // Load data into the table Person. You can modify this code as needed.
        WpfApplication4.DatabaseFCDataSetTableAdapters.PersonTableAdapter databaseFCDataSetPersonTableAdapter = new WpfApplication4.DatabaseFCDataSetTableAdapters.PersonTableAdapter();
        databaseFCDataSetPersonTableAdapter.Fill(databaseFCDataSet.Person);
        System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource personViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("personViewSource")));
        personViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

This isn't so clean and simple as in tutorial. Am I doing something wrong? VS version 2012 and 2015.

Binding to the controls (List Box) is done in xaml automatically after drag'n'drop table from Data Source:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DatabaseFCDataSet x:Key="databaseFCDataSet"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="personViewSource" Source="{Binding Person, Source={StaticResource databaseFCDataSet}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource personViewSource}">
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="211" Margin="36,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="IdPerson"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You haven't assigned your datasource to your control at all. You should assign them to your ItemsSource, and then do Binding as well.

Comment: The binding is done in xaml like this:
'<CollectionViewSource x:Key="personViewSource" Source="{Binding Person, Source={StaticResource databaseFCDataSet}}"/>'

and then:
'Grid DataContext="{StaticResource personViewSource}">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="211" Margin="36,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="152" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="IdPerson"/>'

Comment: please update your question and post your XAML code there. I'll try to answer after you updated your question.

Comment: My question is- in tutorial after drag'n'drop table from Data Source into Main window there are created methods in code behind that query from database (ex. GetCustomersQuery), but when I do it there are no such method (I pasted in first question what I get instead). Is there a way to generate this methods?